# Use a SqlDataReader to read multiple rows at the same time (block read)

Tags: sql, .net, sqldatareader

I'm using a SqlDataReader to retrieve some "SELECT" query from a DBMS.
So far, I read each row one by one in the result set using SqlDataReader.read(), and I process them one by one. When the result set is huge (meaning millions of rows times hundreds of columns), iterating with .read() is very slow. I'm asking: is there a way to do a "block" read from SqlDataReader, meaning that i.e. something like SqlDataReader.read(100) gives me an array of the next 100 rows in the result set?

I thought about doing something like DataTable.Load() to load all the result set in memory, but since the table has a size of several gigabytes, it would't fit in memory.

What would you recommend?
Thanks a lot

Example code:

```
TdConnection conn;
TdCommand cmd;
TdDataReader reader;
IAsyncResult res;

conn = new TdConnection(@"xxxx;");
conn.Open();

cmd = new TdCommand(q,conn);
res = cmd.BeginExecuteReader();

while (!res.IsCompleted);

reader = cmd.EndExecuteReader(res);
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    string sb;
    string currentout = "C:\file";
    string[] row = new string[reader.FieldCount];
    sb = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        row[i] = reader.GetName(i);

    sb = String.Concat(sb,String.Join("\t",row),"\r\n");

    File.WriteAllText(currentout,sb);

    sb = "";

    /* With a test query, the following commented "while" takes 5 minutes 
    /* to iterate over a dataset with 639967 rows x 63 columns (about 300MB)
    /* while(reader.Read());
    */

    /* With the same test query, the following "while block" takes 6 minutes
    /* to iterate over the same dataset AND writing it on a text file
    /* I conclude that I/O writing on text file is fast, and .Read() is very slow
    */
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                row[i] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

        sb = String.Concat(sb,String.Join("\t",row),"\r\n");

        if (sb.Length > 100000)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(currentout,sb);
            sb = "";
        }
    }
    File.AppendAllText(currentout,sb);
}

reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Close();
```

The "Td" components are the Teradata DBMS interface for .NET (but they behave just like "SQL" components).

Comment: The real problem here is: why do you need to load all that data?

Comment: Is the Read slow, or your processing?  Did you profile the code to find the bottleneck?

Comment: Maybe you can transfer your program login to a SQL query and execute that, from the program.

Comment: @Steve because I'm writing a sort of custom "data extractor", so whatever the query is, I need to execute it and export the result set in a custom tab-separated file. So basically my program does not need the data itself, it just needs to write it on a text file.

Comment: I can only think of an async operation that move all your processing in background leaving your interface responsive. You can read a lot about this here on MSDN: [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Steve Yes, I'm doing async operations to archive parallelism among queries, but for this async is not needed since the program is just a console batch program.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm profiling it right now to test timing differences between "while(.read());" and "while(.read()){operations}"

Comment: @LarsTech Test done: the test query outputs 639967 rows x 63 columns (about 300MB); query execution time: 10 seconds; simple dataset fetching without exporting (meaning: "while (.read());"): 5 minutes; dataset fetching with exporting (meaning: "while (.read()){operations}"): 6 minutes. So, it is an acceptable delay export the text file, while 5 minutes to retrieve each row one by one is unlikely to be good... So the "block" can't be done?

Comment: I'm guessing if you really want help with this, you are going to have to show your code.  `5 minutes to retrieve each row` is an obvious problem, but should be easily remedied, but without seeing what you are doing, we can't help you.

Comment: @LarsTech true, I added the code I'm testing, thank you

Comment: Your code would benefit from a code review. Maybe post this to Code Review Stack Exchange. This is frankly terrible code and you'll learn a lot from a review.

Comment: @usr "Example code:" - Code Review Stack Exchange prefers working production-style code. Read the help center on our site to learn more.

Comment: @Pimgd all right, this is probably too low quality and the feedback would be rote.

Answer (score 1):

What's slow here is the quadratic cost of the string concatenation in the loop:

```
sb = String.Concat(sb,String.Join("\t",row),"\r\n");
```

Since this is such a glaring perf problem I'm submitting this as an answer since it probably solves your problem.

If your app is slow, profile it to see *what* is slow.

Unfortunately, ADO.NET is indeed quite CPU heavy when reading data. Nothing you can do about it.